# Converting unicode decimal character to readable Text in swift

Tags: swift, unicode, arabic

I'm trying to convert the arabic unicode decimal values to simple human readable letters ,

```
var arabicPhrase = Array[0].arabic
    println(arabicPhrase)
```

Array[0] contains a string of unicode decimal values , and when i print it ,it prints the unicode values and doesn't convert them to actual arabic letters

Here is an example unicode decimal value i want to convert 
     & #1575;  and equivalent letter is ا .

*(I put a space between the & and # to display the unicode value because it gets converted automatically in the editor)*

keep in mind that this array returns a long string of unicode decimal codes so will need a function that convert to the equivalent letter.

Comment: `&#1575` is a "HTML entity"

Comment: Thanks! didn't know it was an html entity , example works brilliantly